# VF in the same PF cannot obtain the other VF's egress

Tags: linux, nic, intel

I generate 3 VFs in a PF using SR_IOV. Then I use `ip link` to set the VFs trust on, open the promisc mode and send pkts from VF0. But VF1 and VF2 cannot obtain the egress from VF0, the pkts go through to the other endpoint PF directorly.

I wanna know how can I catch the VF0's egress on VF1 or VF2 without set the pkts' dstmac?

My NIC is **X710** and I use the command below to setup the VFs:

```
ip link set <pf> vf 0 trust on
ip link set <pf> vf 1 trust on
ip link set <pf> vf 2 trust on

ethtool --set-priv-flags <pf> vf-true-promisc-support on


ip link set <vf0> promisc on
ip link set <vf1> promisc on
ip link set <vf1> promisc on
```

Comment: That's not a field I know (nor can test), but I would check this setting: [loopback](https://github.com/dmarion/i40e/blob/7dd040f5f31b1bae427b24e58ea193a0299f8812/README#L1512)

Comment: I find there is no loopback file in this path. There are only egress_mirror and ingress_mirror